# How to export results in Uiautomator

Tags: android-uiautomator

The UiAutomator output is currently displayed in CMD prompt.

When i run the tests the output is displayed in Command prompt.How to export this to .txt file/html file.

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like:

```
adb shell "uiautomator runtest test.jar -c test_class" >> file.txt
```

The above code appends the output into file.txt

Comment: Gabriel: I'm not using adb.

Comment: @gabriel-porumb  What do you use for reporting for uiautomator?

Comment: @TimBo: I either import the android.utils.log and use log.d method to put a debug message in logcat and then parse the logcat output.
More details here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Or I just use stdout.printline and parse the output taken from running the test. 

If the test passes, there usually is the "OK" indicator in stdout after all the info from each test: instrumentation, what method is running (if I'm not mistaken)

Fortunately, we have an in-house developed framework for running all the tests.

Answer (score 0):

We can convert the console output results into standard junit xml result by using the following github project.

https://github.com/dpreussler/automator-log-converter

Usage

- Initially redirect your output to text file format as mentioned above.

With automator-log-convertor:

- Build the jar file with the `./gradlew jar` command
- Run `java –jar path-to\automator-log-converter-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar path-to\output.text` where the path to the uiautomator jar file will be in `build/libs/` directory

This will convert the text file format to standard junit xml format.